# JavaFX Button style issue when touched on Windows 8

Tags: css, windows, touch, javafx-8

When a JavaFX button is touched, the CSS pseudo-class `pressed` is not always being called.

All the button events (onAction, onTouchPressed, onMousePressed, etc) are being called as expected, it's just its style that is behaving inconsistently. Most of times the button simply doesn't change when it is touched.

I've never seen anyone complaining about this, so I suppose it's a driver problem.

My environment is:

Laptop

```
Acer Aspire R7-572
```

OS

```
Windows 8.1 64 bits
```

Java

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Test application:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane rootPane = new FlowPane();
        Button button = new Button("Touch me");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 800, 600);
        rootPane.getChildren().add(button);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is a touch screen issue.  Do you get the same styling issue if you use touch pad or a mouse rather than touching the screen?

Comment: If I use touch pad or mouse, it works properly. It might be a touch screen issue, but its really weird that the style seems to stay "unsynchronized" while all the button events are being called whenever a touch occurs. It's worth to mention that sometimes it works as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue on windows 8.1. I tried with 3 different touch screen models. I guess this is a javafx issue. I have not yet tested with 1.8u40 but I'll try soon.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but to add some additional information to this problem, as well as a bit of experimentation...  Programmatically, I can have all my buttons working graphically without any issue.  The problem seems to be how the CSS files are handled.  Using a CSS file configured as follows...

```
.button:pressed{
     -fx-background-color: #333333;
}
.button{
     -fx-background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

Then I end up having a button that will only depress (graphically) when I touch it and slide my finger on it.  As far as I know there is no 'touch slide' pseudo class for CSS and nor did I have anything defined if there were.  It just seems like CSS (which this is probably wrong terminology) doesn't detect a touch press the same way it detects a mouse press.

If I use for example...

```
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #DDDDDD"));

setOnTouchPressed(e -> button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #333333"));
setOnTouchReleased(e -> button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #DDDDDD"));
```

the button will go from light (to start with), to dark (on touch pressed) to light (on touch release).  So I doubt it's a driver issue.  It seems unless there is some pseudo class for touch input added to CSS, in the mean time any touch-screen development will need to be done with pure code.

Comment: This makes sense, will test it when I have time. Giving the growing popularity of touch based applications, It would be a shame if such an important pseudo class is missing. Someone filed this bug on Jira though: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139118